# stability of parabolic problems where nonhomogeneous term in $L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$

Tags: finite-element-method

There is a problem in this estimate. In **Part 2**, We can't derive the second inequality from the first inequality in **Part 2**. The main reason is the last term on the RHS in the first inequality is in $\|\cdot\|_1$ not $\|\cdot\|_0$.

How can I fix this proof or are there any stability result controlling $\tau \sum_{n=1}^k\|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|_0^2$  where $f\in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$.

For your convenience, you can focus on **Part 2**. Also I have shown other parts in the proof  for your reference.

---

**Here is the problem description and the proof**

Let's consider a simple parabolic equation (in variational form).

Assume $f\in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$. Find $u\in H^1(\Omega )$ such that $u(\cdot,0)=u_0$ and $u(x,t)=g(x,t)$ on $\partial \Omega \times (0,T)$ and 
\begin{equation}
(u_t,v)+a(u,v)=(f,v) ~~\forall v\in H^1_0(\Omega)
\end{equation}
for almost all $t\in (0,T)$ where $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ are given by
$$
a(w,v)=\int_{\Omega} a(x) \nabla w\cdot \nabla v ~dx ,~~~f(v)=\int_{\Omega} f(x)v(x)~dx
$$
(Actually, I only concern about the case that $a(x)\equiv 1)$

Then the finite element approximation can be formulated as follows:

Find $u_h^n\in V_0^h $ such that $u^0_h=\prod_h u_0$ and for $n=0,1,...,M:$
\begin{equation}\label{1}
(\partial_\tau u_h^n , v_h)+a(u^n_h,v_h)=(f^n,v_h)~~\forall v_h\in V_0^h
\end{equation}

**Stability estimates**  We establish some stability estimates for the finite element solution $\{u_h^n\}$.

**Part 1:**
Let $v_h=\tau u_h^n$ in approximation formulation, we have
\begin{equation}\label{dstability2}
\frac{1}{2}\|u^n_h\|_0^2 -\frac{1}{2}\|u^{n-1}_h\|_0^2+\tau\|u_h^n\|_1^2\leq \tau \|f^n\|_{-1}\|u_h^n\|_1\leq \frac{1}{2}\tau\|f^n\|_{-1}^2+\frac{1}{2}\tau\|u_h^n\|_{1}^2
\end{equation}

Summing up over $n=1,2,...,k\leq M,$
\begin{equation}
\|u_h^k\|_0^2+\sum_{n=1}^k\tau\|u_h^n\|_1^2\leq \tau \sum_{n=1}^k\|f^n\|_{-1}^2+\|u_h^0\|_0^2= \tau \sum_{n=1}^k\|f^n\|_{-1}^2+\|\prod\nolimits_h u_0\|_0^2
\end{equation}

**Part 2:**

Now taking $v_h=\tau \partial_\tau u_h^n$ in approximation formulation, we get
\begin{equation}
\tau \|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|_0^2+\frac{1}{2}\|u_h^n\|_1^2-\frac{1}{2}\|u_h^{n-1}\|_1^2\leq \tau\langle f^n,\partial_\tau u_h^n\rangle \leq \frac{1}{2}\tau\|f^n\|_{-1}^2+\frac{1}{2}\tau\|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|_1^2
\end{equation}

Summing up over $n=1,2,...,k\leq M$. we derive
\begin{equation}
\tau \sum_{n=1}^k\|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|_0^2+\|u_h^k\|_1^2\leq \|u_h^0\|_1^2+\tau\sum_{n=1}^k\|f^n\|_{-1}^2
\end{equation}

**Part 3:**

Next, we will estimate the dual norm of $\partial_\tau u_h^n$. For this, we introduce a $L^2-$projection $Q_h: L^2(\Omega)\to V_0^h$ by
\begin{equation}
(Q_h w, v_h)=(w,v_h) ~~~\forall v_h\in V_0^h.
\end{equation}

Then we can show 
\begin{equation}
\|w-Q_h w\|_0\leq Ch |w|_1, ~~~~~\|Q_h w\|_s\leq C\|w\|_s ~~~\text{ for } s=0,1.
\end{equation}

Now for any $\phi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, we derive
\begin{equation}
(\partial_\tau u_h^n, \phi)=(\partial u_h^n, \phi-Q_h \phi)- (\nabla u_h^n, \nabla Q_h \phi)+ \langle f^n, Q_h \phi\rangle.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|(\partial_\tau u_h^n, \phi)|&=\|\partial u_h^n\|_0\| \phi-Q_h \phi\|_0+\|u_h^n\|_1\|\nabla Q_h \phi\|_1+ \|f^n\|_{-1}\| Q_h \phi \|_1\\
& \leq C(h\|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|_0+\|u_h^n\|_1+\|f^n\|_{-1})\|\phi\|_1.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This implies that
\begin{equation}
\tau \sum_{n=1}^M\|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|^2_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \leq C \tau \sum_{n=1}^M \{h^2\|\partial_\tau u_h^n\|_0^2+\|u_h^n\|_1^2+\|f^n\|_{-1}^2\}.
\end{equation}

Comment: I am following a proof where $f$ is assumed to be in the space $L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))$ , I have presented the proof in the following link. 
                         
        https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5j0k6kr3rmgq2a/Proof%20.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I suggest you forget the finite element approximation and focus on the time discretization alone. I also suggest that you write explicitly $\partial_\tau u^n=(u^n-u^{n-1})/\tau$. I wouldn't be surprised if the stability you expect needed $f\in L^2(O,T;L^2)$.

Comment: @Jean Duchon Thanks for your suggestion. It really needs $f\in L^2（0，T; L^2(\Omega))$ to complete the proof of  stability result. The assumption $f\in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$ is not enough.